# Move a folder, not item.move

Tags: vba, outlook, directory

I'm trying to put some order in my mailbox, I've set several macros to order email based on very specific preferences, that outlook rules can't manage (I think ...)

I end up with several folder, with several conversations inside of it.
I just want to move folders with old conversations to another folder.

I'm trying to move a folder with all his content, including subfolders, and emails ...

I can code a recursive function for this, but I just want to be sure there's no other coding options.

```
Folder.Move(ColdCaseFolder)
```

Won't work ...

I'm used to VBA macroing, but I couldn't find any article on MSDN about moving folders, only items ...

Answer (score 1):

The Folder class from the Outlook object model doesn't provide the Move method. You need to use the [MoveTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865640(v=office.15).aspx) method instead. For example:

```
Sub MoveFolder() 
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder 

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
  Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("My Test Contacts") 
  myNewFolder.MoveTo myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a Charm ! Thank you so much ! (and Yeah, i'm feeling a bit stupid to NOT have figure this out alone ...) :) Seeya !